# avaudioplayer play music in background

Tags: xcode

I have a problem with AVAudioPlayer in background, everything works but when I have the controls in the lock screen and I click on the pause button the control receive the event but the lock screen with controls disappears. I want that lock screen remain with controls like Music app.

I put these lines in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
```

and then :

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


   [[UIApplication sharedApplication]beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
   [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{ return YES; }

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {


    //End recieving events
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self resignFirstResponder];

     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //if it is a remote control event handle it correctly

    if (event.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {
        if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause) {

            [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_icon.png"]
                                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [self.audioPlayer pauseAudio];
            self.isPaused = FALSE;
        }
        else if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay){

            if (!self.isPaused) {
                [self.playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"]
                                           forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                //start a timer to update the time label display
                self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                              target:self
                                                            selector:@selector(updateTime:)
                                                            userInfo:nil
                                                             repeats:YES];

                [self.audioPlayer playAudio];
                self.isPaused = TRUE;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you did. Post some code

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution !!

Using this property :
        @property MPNowPlayingInfoCenter* nowPlayingInfo;

I have to add these lines on my viewDidLoad :

```
    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@1.0f forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
```